# How to keep tab active when page is reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When `Save` button is clicked page gets reloaded like so, with putting additional `parameter` in `url`:

```
window.location.replace('https://www.servis-racunara.net/pages/users.php?new_column_added');
```

So, this is how I'm checking weather parameter is set within url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('new_column_added') > -1) {}
});
```

So, page looks like this:[image]

When there is `new_column_added` within url(i.e. when Save button is clicked), page should reload, but tab `Edit User List` should be active and his content should be there as well. This is how tabs are created using `Bootstrap`:

```
<ul id="mainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs  users-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li id="glavniUseri" role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">View Users</a></li>
   <li id="editUsers" role="presentation"><a href="#edit-user-list" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Edit User List</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Target Groups</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">API</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is how I managed to make `Edit User List` active:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('new_column_added') > -1) {
        console.log('radii ovoo');
        $('#glavniUseri').removeClass('active');
        $('#editUsers').addClass('active');
});
```

But all this does is to make `Edit User List` active, but content of `View Users` tab gets loaded, after the reload. I also tried doing this:

```
$(document).on('load', function () {
            var $link = $('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]');
            $link.parent().removeClass('active');
            var tabLink = $link.attr('href');
            $('#mainTabs a[href="' + tabLink + '"]').tab('show');
        });
```

But this is not working as well. I know similar questions have been asked before, but it seems like none of solutions fits my situation. So, if you have some idea, please help, I'm stuck with this.

Comment: whats the least compatibility for browsers ?
 if I understand correctly after completion of asyc save u want to modify the url. 
This we can do without reload if min browser is IE9.

Comment: When you submit data and the page reloads, the existing function from javascript are reset. Why not use AJAX? This will allow you to submit data to an external server-side file without reloading the page meaning any current javascript running will not stop and restart. This will also speed things up as the client doesn't have to wait for the page to load again.

Comment: All I want is just when save button is clicked, page to get reloaded and stay within last active tab.

Comment: @NewToJS I am using AJAX(and this reload is from it's success part), but I need this reload because of some other PHP part.

Comment: use localstograge/cookies to save the state

Comment: OK, in that case, did you try clicking the link, in stead of making it active.. this will make the link active as well as load the content
some thing like :
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('new_column_added') > -1) {
        $('#editUsers').click();
});

Comment: @Dreamweaver you mean like simulating click on the link form js code? Have no idea how to do that.

Comment: yes, I have added code in comment, just try that

Comment: I'm confused to why you would have the page reload if you are already using AJAX but DreamWeaver's idea should work. With your current source code, does it output `radii ovoo` from the `console.log('radii ovoo');`?

Comment: Tried, not working. It still loads content of default(first) tab. Even tried to give id to `<a>` tag and do this: $('#editUsersLink').click(); but no results, again.

Comment: @NewToJS I need that reload because of other PHP code that needs to count changes made in database. Yes, it outputs 'radii ovoo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('new_column_added') > -1) {
        console.log('radii ovoo');
        $('#glavniUseri').removeClass('active');
        $('#editUsers').addClass('active');
         $('#edit-user-list').parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#edit-user-list').addClass('active');
});
```

or:

```
$('a[href="#edit-user-list"]').tab('show');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8zjhamu/